# How to redirect traffic for my url to my own linux server?

Tags: url, server, dns

I "own" a URL www.example.com which is currently hosted by One.com. I recently built my own server running a LAMP stack and it serves pages to the internet from /html as it should, but is only accessible via numeric IP address. In the past I've re-assigned the name servers for URL's but only using a hosting company's "dashboard" or GUI. I've read about changing the DNS settings in Ubuntu (my server is running 18.04) and also I've researched what I can into Google's public DNS and DynDNS services.

So I have two sets of questions. First, is it possible to "connect" or "bind" a URL to the static IP address of my own server without using a DNS service? Can it be done through any kind of public registry and if not, what are the least expensive but still reliable options?

Second, is basically "Why bother?" I do understand the value of a human-readable address but also, the address bar isn't realistically used anymore. Most of the security value of having human readable addresses depends on users actually looking at the address bar so that's becoming a moot argument. People only navigate the web now through links and Google searches, and the address bar is essentially a developer tool. It seems like I can pretty much replace the need for DNS with masked links and meta titles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set your domain's "A Record" in DNS to point to your server's IP address. While not neccessary, you can configure Apache to respond to the correct domain with virtualhosts [https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/name-based.html ], but you will need the DNS configured correctly first.

It is not possible to bind a domain to an IP address without DNS - DNS or Domain Name System is THE authoritative system for doing so. It's how the world wide web functions.

Here is some additional reading on what DNS does and why it's important: https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/what-is-dns/

Comment: Will the current hosting provider retain the options in their dashboard for me to change the dns records after the URL no longer directs to their servers? In other words, if I change the DNS through One.com to point to my own server, will I continue to be able to use One.com to change the DNS for that URL in the future or will I need another service for that?